# Moment.js get day name from date

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, momentjs

I'm using jquery and moment.js for a custom calendar.

I have a date object in a variable `myDate` like :

```
 Object { date="2014-12-23 14:00:00", timezone_type=3, timezone="Europe/Paris"}
```

I want, using moment.js (or not) get the day name of this date, in my example i need to get : `tuesday`

Ideas ? Thanks

Comment: moment().format('dddd'); should work

Comment: already tried, if i use moment(mydate).format('dddd') i have invalid date in error

Comment: probably is mydate your problem

Answer (score 263, accepted):

With moment you can parse the date string you have:

```
var dt = moment(myDate.date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

That's for UTC, you'll have to convert the time zone from that point if you so desire.

Then you can get the day of the week:

```
dt.format('dddd');
```

And you can get the 3 letter format weekday by

```
dt.format('dddd').substring(0,3)
```

Comment: There are so many non-working answers out there.  This is the one that works!

Answer (score 79):

### code

```
var mydate = "2017-06-28T00:00:00";
var weekDayName =  moment(mydate).format('dddd');
console.log(weekDayName);
```

mydate is the input date. The variable weekDayName get the name of the day.
Here the output is

### Output

Wednesday

```js
var mydate = "2017-08-30T00:00:00";
console.log(moment(mydate).format('dddd')); // Wednesday
console.log(moment(mydate).format('ddd'));  // Wed
console.log('Day in number[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]: '+moment(mydate).format('d')); // Day in number[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]: 3
console.log(moment(mydate).format('MMM'));  // Aug
console.log(moment(mydate).format('MMMM'));  // August
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var mydate = "2017-06-28T00:00:00";
var weekDayName =  moment(mydate).format('ddd');
console.log(weekDayName);
```

Result: Wed

```
var mydate = "2017-06-28T00:00:00";
var weekDayName =  moment(mydate).format('dddd');
console.log(weekDayName);
```

Result: Wednesday