# How to get the Day names and Number of days based on month and year

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get the week names ( sunday, monday, tuesday... ) and number of days based on the month and year...

```js
daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

let dys = this.daysInMonth(this.selected_from.getMonth() + 1, selected_year);

for (let a = 1; a <= dys; a++) {
  console.log(a, 'a')
}

console.log(dys, 'dys');
```

By using this code i can get the number of days, but how to get the week names ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
getDayNames(year: number, month: number) {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        var d = new Date(year, month, i);
        var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
        console.log(i + ' ' + dayName);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Since moths are declared as 0-11 and not like 1-12 I have edited code so you can enter 1 for january, 2 for february and so...

```
getDayNames(year: number, month: number) {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        var d = new Date(year, month - 1, i);
        var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
        console.log(i + ' ' + dayName);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @vinaykumar0459 I have edited answer so now you can enter exact number of month.

Comment: @vinaykumar0459  I have changed this part of code: `var d = new Date(year, month - 1, i);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for *such** date operations.

### Here's how to get the days names by a month and an year, using moment.js

```js
const getDayNames = (month, year) => {
  const daysInMonth = moment(`${month}-01-${year}`, 'MM-DD-YYYY').daysInMonth()
  const names = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    let date = moment(`${month}-${i}-${year}`, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
    let dayName = date.format('dddd')

    names.push(`${dayName} - ${date.format('MM-DD-YYYY')}`)
  }
  
  return names
}

console.log(getDayNames(5, 2018))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

### * Should we use an external library?

As always, here we can give you very generalized solution, without knowing the big picture (the context). It's on your own to weight - should or should not use a date library. If your app relies on complex dates operations - therefore it will be better to use one for sure.

According to your case (without knowing the context), it's controversial should or should not. It's not a complex functionality, but personally I'll prefer using it for the following reasons:

1. As you can see in the code snippet, moment.js give us *the week day names*, and easily you can enable localization / internationalization for your users.
2. You operate with moment.js API, which is much cleaner and imperative than `Date()` API, that will reduce the risk of getting things wrong.

When you have complex date operations, then it's always a good decision to use a *date library*, instead of writing your own functions, because there're a lot of complexities that you have to manage and consider by yourself (at a given point of time).

For example:

- You want to support internationalization for the day names (translate the day name, according the user's language).
- Dates manipulations (Add / Substract days).
- Dates formatting.
- And many other cases (hidden on a first sign)

Be careful and please don't reinvent the wheel, especially for *complex date* operations! :)

Credits:

1. [Get dates in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553652/using-moment-js-to-get-number-of-days-in-current-month)
2. [Get date name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669019/jquery-moment-js-get-day-name-from-date)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't want to use moment.js in my application.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var day = "";
    switch(n) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;
    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day;
}
```

Refer : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that creates a list of moment objects for each day of the month.
Lines can be optimized but kept it simple for clarity.

```
// function that gets all the days in a month with the corresponding arguments passed in
    // Year, Month arguments are specified by the user, pass in the year in the month to find out the total amout of days in that month.
    getDaysArrayByMonth(year,month){
        // adding one to month because when you call moment.month() it returns 0-11 months instead of 1-12
        const monthNum = month + 1;
        // create moment object with formatted string
        const year_month_string = monthNum.toString()+"-"+year.toString();  
        const FirstDayofMonth = moment(year_month_string,"MM-YYYY");

        // find the number of days in the month from the moment object
        var daysInMonth = FirstDayofMonth.daysInMonth();
        
        // arr which will store all days in the month
        var daysArr = [];
        // create dayint variable to increment day of the month
        var dayInt = 1;
        // create string for creating moment object, will modify it in a loop to access all days of that month
        var curDayofMonthString = "0"+dayInt.toString()+"-"+monthNum.toString()+"-"+year.toString();
        // create moment obj with curDayofMonthString
        var curDayofMonth = moment(curDayofMonthString,"DD-MM-YYYY");
        
        // loop for total number of days in month to append all days to daysArr
        while(daysInMonth){
            // append day
            daysArr.push(curDayofMonth);
            // inc day and format string depending if day is doble digits or not
            dayInt++;
            if(dayInt > 9){
                curDayofMonthString = dayInt.toString()+"-"+monthNum.toString()+"-"+year.toString();
            }else{
                curDayofMonthString = "0"+dayInt.toString()+"-"+monthNum.toString()+"-"+year.toString();
            }
            // create new moment obj
            curDayofMonth = moment(curDayofMonthString,"DD-MM-YYYY");
            daysInMonth--;
        }
        // return array with information on the month
        return daysArr;
    }
```

You can then access the days like this

```
Array.from(MomentObjDaysInMonthArray).forEach(obj =>{
    console.log(obj.day());
});
```

Where:
0: Sunday
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
5: Friday
6: Saturday