# Convert date from Day of Week to Day Name

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to manipulate my dates.
I retrieve the data in which the field day is represented as numeral, like 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday and so on.
How can I convert those int back to "Monday, Tuesday" etc using moment.js?

Comment: can you give an example of a date string you're receiving?

Comment: `let dayName = {1:"Monday", 2: "Tuesday" ........ }[ dayNumeral ]`
Where `dayNumeral` is your day numeral

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery moment.js get day name from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669019/jquery-moment-js-get-day-name-from-date)

Answer (score 4):

Use `day(arg)` method to retrieve the data object and then use `format("dddd")` to retrieve the day of week string.

```js
var date = moment();
let dayNumber = 4;
let dayString = date.day(dayNumber).format("dddd");
console.log(dayString);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array of strings with the days of the week in the order that you want:

```js
    const daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    function getDayOfWeek(number){
        return daysOfWeek[number];
    }
```

Comment: If 1 is the lowest number which will be returned as day-reference, the index should be `number-1` {Which is the case if the ISO day is returned by moment.js}

Comment: In the question  Monday = 1, not 0

Comment: The first day in the array should be Sunday, and to deal with values greater than 6 you need `daysOfWeek[number % 7];`. ;-)