# Given a selected year, I need to calculate the first day and the last day of that year in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Given a selected year, for example: "2020". I need to calculate with JavaScript the first and the last day of the selected year in format: "2020-01-01" and "2020-12-31"

Can someone help me with this? It will be possible doing it with Moment.js? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first day shall always be 1 jan and last is 31st dec of the gregorian calendar right ?

Comment: The dates `January 01` and `December 31` is constant right? So why do you want to do it with `moment js` ? You can simply add `01-01` and `12-31` after the given year. If you want to find the day of that date, Then you can use `moment js`.

Comment: Do you want the name of the day, like monday?

Comment: Not exactly clear how moment.js fits into the problem, but take a look at the following, which provides a reference for all the javascript date functions you might ever need:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for please check this answer using moment.js https://stackoverflow.com/a/27669095/5194017 You have to just pass date "01-01-2020" and get the day name using .format()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
CalculateDates = function(year){
    console.log('first day: ' + new Date(year, 0, 1, 4).toJSON().split('T')[0]);
    console.log('last day: '  + new Date(year, 12, 0, 4).toJSON().split('T')[0]);
}
CalculateDates(2019)
```

Comment: For me, that returns `first day: 2018-12-31` and `last day: 2019-12-30`. There is no reason to involve either a Date object or JSON. And why set the hour to 4? I'll guess that's your local timezone offset.

Comment: It depends on your time zone. try to add more hours and it will solve it:
new Date(year, 0, 1, 12)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```js
var formatDate = function(year, month, day)
{
    if (month < 10) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day < 10) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

var printDate = function(year){
   console.log("Frist day: " + formatDate(year, 1, 1));
   console.log("Last day: " + formatDate(year, 12, 31));
}

printDate(2020);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and fastest approach is to not "calculate" anything. You don't need to.

```js
function firstOfYear(year) {
  return `${year}-01-01`;
}

function lastOfYear(year) {
  return `${year}-12-31`;
}

const start = firstOfYear(2020); // 2020-01-01
const end = lastOfYear(2020); // 2020-12-31
```

You might not even need the functions, depending on your use case.

These functions aren't especially reusable, so if you have other dates you'd like to format then some of the other answers provided will be more flexible. But if all you need to do is get the first and last of the year, then I recommend you keep it simple.